How to prevent reordering of calls to a function that prints log messages in C?
typedef enum {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
} my_enum;

/**
 * @warning If random is NULL or blabla is invalid the behavior of this function is undefined.
 */
int foo(int *random, my_enum blabla)
{
    //Prints: [DBG][<timestamp>][<thread_name>][foo:<line_no>]: Entering - Hello world!
    LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING("%s", "Hello world!");
    int ret_code = 0;
    
    *random = 50;
    ret_code = do_something(*random, blabla);
    
    //Prints: [DBG][<timestamp>][<thread_name>][foo:<line_no>]: Exiting - <ret_code>
    LOG_DEBUG_EXITING("%d", ret_code);
    return ret_code;
}

I'm developing a portable multi-thread application, that can run on embedded and non-embedded systems, that works with different compilers that support at least c99.
Some platforms I work on do not have a debugger, and therefore intercepting bugs is quite difficult, the only tool that can help me in these situations are the log messages generated by the application itself.
So in all the functions of this application I added the LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() and LOG_DEBUG_EXITING() macros so that I can track the execution of the application.
These macros/functions are designed to ensure that the message has been printed out once they finish executing, or at most the message to be printed has been queued somewhere (maybe in another process) to be printed as soon as possible, this is implementation and platform dependant, in any case all messages are printed out even if the application crashes due to a bug.
This above is a more or less a real example in my application.
If foo() is called in one of the following ways it will crash the application:
int random;
foo(NULL, A); //It will crash when foo() tries to assign 100 to the address pointed to by random
foo(&random, 1000); //Crash because the bheaviour of do_something() is not defined if blabla is out of range

I can easily find out where in the code the application crashed from the log messages, but I'm worried that the compiler might change the macro calling order, for example like this:
int foo(int *random, my_enum blabla)
{
    int ret_code = 0;
    
    *random = 50;
    ret_code = do_something(*random, blabla);
    
    //Prints: [DBG][<timestamp>][<thread_name>][foo:<line_no>]: Entering - Hello world!
    LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING("%s", "Hello world!");

    //Prints: [DBG][<timestamp>][<thread_name>][foo:<line_no>]: Exiting - <ret_code>
    LOG_DEBUG_EXITING("%d", ret_code);
    return ret_code;
}

in this case the application would crash without any message being printed out.
How can I prevent the compiler/CPU from changing the calling order of LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING()?
EDIT
The input parameters of foo() and do_something() are not checked on purpose, the idea is that we do not protect our application from bad-coding, but we still want to be able to catch these bugs when necessary.

What makes you think the order is changed?  Did you inspect the assembly to see if the is the case?

The compiler isn't allowed to reorder statements if it would cause an observable difference in output.

Compiler will only reorder statements if it can prove the observable result is the same, or if there's UB somewhere.

@dbush No I have not inspected the assembly, but it doesn't even make sense to do so, because this application has to run on different platforms and with different compilers that we don't even know.

There's a sequence point between statements. You may be confusing this with reordering of function arguments.

@pmg Hmm, there's UB when it does *random = 50; and random == NULL. That could be a problem.

The "reordering" might happen between messages coming from different threads. But it is not a reordering, it is just the natural order of the things happening, even if they might happen in different order between the runs.

If application crashes due to Undefined Behavior in the code, don't expect any defined execution order. That's why parameters checking practice exists.

@Barmar But couldn't the compiler decide to move LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() after the call to do_something() because this change doesn't produce any observable effect in output?

C was designed by (good) programmers for (good) programmers. You (apparently) are designing your library for bad programmers... ... so don't rely on C philosophy: test everything, everywhere, double check arguments, abort execution rather than returning an error code, ...

If do_something() has any side effects, doing them in a different order is an observable change.

@pmg One point of logging like this is to catch when you've made a mistake, like forgetting to validate an argument properly. It's a Catch-22 if you have to do proper validation so you can have debugging statements.

Important missing information, please [edit] your question to add: Are all your compilers compliant to the C99 standard? If so, did you read the standard's annex C about sequence points? If so, why did it not help you?

Are you aware of the compiler's instrumentation used for coverage analysis? Try it and see how you can use the results to detect cases of different numbers of function entries and exits.

"couldn't the compiler decide to move LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() after the call to do_something() because this change doesn't produce any observable effect in output?" -- the compiler has no notion of "output". The compiler would not make any chances that would produce any observable effect period.

@pmg abort execution rather than returning an error code  I want NOTHING to do with code from some random lib dev who arrogates to himself the right to decide when to kill my application.

@Barmar Function calls are also sequence points.  IMO any compiler that reorders operations across sequence points is beyond buggy - it's irreparably broken.

@ParminderSingh I'd recommend starting each logged line with an ISO8601-formatted date/time so sorting logs from multiple sources naturally results in a time-ordered sequence.  Also make sure hostname, executable name, process id, and thread id fields can be easily sorted or otherwise located.

@AndrewHenle that was meant as a coding philosophy for code designed for bad programmers; which I don't think applies to the vast majority of C programmers.

@pmg Bad programmers and C pretty much leaves you up a certain creek without a boat - forget the paddle. ;-)

The C standard (C17 5.1.2.3) speaks of "observable behavior" which are things that must not be changed during optimization.
Writing to a log ultimately means writing to some manner of volatile qualified register, like the UART peripheral hardware. Accessing a volatile variable is a side effect which cannot get optimized away or re-ordered, so the re-ordering you describe cannot happen in conforming C.
Similarly, modifying any non-volatile variable (or a file) is also a side effect and if that one is a needed side effect - for example because you are passing the variable to a print function the next thing you do - then it cannot get optimized out or re-ordered across the function call. The compiler may otherwise optimize the code in ways that don't affect the behavior, like putting the variable in a register instead of the stack etc.
Now of course if your program is in a state of chaos because of bugs and undefined behavior, you'll have to analyze what will happen on the assembler and memory level.

Changing the access order of volatile variables certainly has a side effect, so the compiler cannot change their order, but that was not my question.
What you are implicitly telling me is that the compiler cannot swap the execution order of LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() with LOG_DEBUG_EXITING(), because it would have side effects (messages printed in the wrong order), but the compiler may decide to move LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() immediately after the line *random = 50;, because there would be no observable side effects, the messages would still be printed in the correct order.

I think the answer to my question is, no I cannot prevent the compiler from changing the order of the LOG_DEBUG_xxx() functions/macros, or at least not in a simple way.

@ParminderSingh "but the compiler may decide to move LOG_DEBUG_ENTERING() immediately after the line *random = 50;" No. ret_code = ... is sequenced before the volatile access and it ends with ; which is a sequence point. All side effects must be evaluated before that sequence point. volatile access must be done strictly according to those rules (C17 5.1.2.3). It cannot be re-ordered.

@ParminderSingh "I think the answer to my question is, no I cannot prevent the compiler from changing the order" Your conforming C compiler is not allowed to change the order. If you are using a non-conforming non-C compiler, well then that is a problem.

Actually you are right! I read more carefully the point 5.1.2.3p2 of the c99 standard, which says that even "modifying an object" is considered a side effect, so even a simple assignment to a variable is considered to have a side effect. I got confused by this question, but I just realized they were talking about c++, where from what I understand the assignment to a (non-volatile) variable is not considered an operation with side effects.
